# Core dump of a multithreaded program

Tags: multithreading, unix, coredump

i have regularly worked with single threaded programs.
i never saw a multithreded program crashing since i havent worked on any.

is there any difference between both the core dumps?
is there any additional information provided in the core dump of a multithreaded program when compared to a single threaded program?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a full dump, you'll have the entire address space of the process. That includes loaded modules, stacks for each thread and so on. Have a look at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5174/core-4.html#scrolltoc) for additional info. In short the dump will have the necessary info to debug multiple threads. Still may not be easy though.